Monitoring data exflitration
I've been tasked with coming up with some mechanism that would allow me to detect when a database user queries a certain table in our system and a large result set is returned (say over 1000 rows). This is done under the premise that these large queries might be part of a data exfiltration attempt and should be reviewed by data security.
I want to log all queries where:
data from table X is included in the result set.
The results contains more than 1000 rows.
How would I go about capturing this information?
Can this be accomplished using extended events? Query Store?

Perhaps you can implement this with an Extended Event like this.
You probably want to finetune this, for example removing SSMS or other internal stuff.
It will fetch the rpc_completed and batch_completed where the row_count > 1000.
I assumed it would make sense to also retrieve the client_hostname and client_app_name when it happens.
CREATE EVENT SESSION [MoreThan1000RowsReturned] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.rpc_completed(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname)
    WHERE ([row_count]>(1000))),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_completed(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname)
    WHERE ([row_count]>(1000)))
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'MoreThan1000RowsReturned',max_file_size=(100))
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=OFF)
GO

